# Div will not position inline

Tags: css

I have a div width at 1000px and height at 100% but when i try and make anothe div next to it (on the right) with the following properties:

```
margin-right: 20%;
border:  1px solid;
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 10px;
```

The div appears at the bottom of where the main container div ends.

What is wrong?

Comment: How wide is the container and have you tried applying float: left; on the div to the left?

Comment: Thank you. Was missing a floatL left

Answer (score 1):

You can assign float:left; or display:inline-block; to the first div.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat confusing, but place your second div before your first in your code, then the float will affect it. Right now, the first div is display:block, which pushes down the next line.

right now it's :

```
<div id="1">
<div id="2" style="float:right">
```

change it to

```
<div id="2" style="float:right">
<div id="1">
```

Comment: Just a note, while this will achieve the desired result, generally moving markup for the sole purpose of presentation is frowned upon. Your HTML/content should flow logically and CSS should dictate your layout. Instead of adjusting the markup, put float: left on the div with id="1" in your example.

Comment: oh yes, of course, i would want to highly deter you from doing inline styles unless absolutely necessary. i was just trying to highlight how sometimes page flow can be confusing.